# Maxima (CAS): How to keep session history?

Tags: maxima

When starting a new session, Maxima forgets the history of the executed commands of the previous session. When I use up arrow, nothing shows up.

Can one force Maxima to keep the history of its sessions?

To be precise, I am taking about Maxima under Linux, but the question could be relevant for other OS's as well.

Comment: Use `rmaxima` or `rlwrap maxima`